# Highlighting first time a value appears in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, countif

Is it possible to highlight cells where a value appears for the first time?

Eg:

```
A1 = 1
A2 = 2
A3 = 3
A4 = 4
A5 = 1
A6 = 2
```

So in the above A1-A4 would be highlighted but A5-A6 wouldn't as they are repeats of the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now if I wanted the lower numbers to be classed as the first entry, could I reverse this in some way? Ie using the above example it would be cells A3-A6 that would show as the first entries and A1-A2 wouldn't be highlighted

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,ROW(A:A), ">="&ROW(A1)))=1
```

[image]

and the reverse of it would be:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A1)))=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: with apply to range set `A1:A1000` take a look at the [**Example sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Olwd14iCrFtvl6UtzWGow01dIinthNUsmkighSvM_0A/edit?usp=sharing)

> Click Format and then Conditional formatting 
> Under the "Format cells if" drop-down menu, click Custom formula

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1
```

[image]

lock `$` the row of the range of [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) function to count only the immediate left cell and what above it till `A1`

Comment: Thanks @Osm, that has worked! Now if I wanted the lower numbers to be classed as the first entry, could I reverse this in some way? Ie using the above example it would be cells A3-A6 that would show as the first entries and A1-A2 wouldn't be highlighted

Comment: It could be reversed simply by =COUNTIF(A1:A,A1)=1